# Speeding up VS2010 when working with WF4 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4

I am developing on our development server. Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit OS, 256GB of RAM, 16 CPU machine.  VS2010 with SP1 installed.

I have a huge workflow (around 30K lines in the XAMLX file).  Every time I make even a small change in an activity, like changing the display name, it takes about 2-3 minutes to register the change.  VS2010 is unresponsive all this time.  It is extremely frustrating.

What is causing this and how can I make it run faster?  Is there any setting in VS2010 that will make this run faster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of the delay is the associated work flow designer trying to update to the change you just made.  It's doing so synchronously on the UI thread and hence you see the delay.

The only way I can think of to stop this is to not open the designer.  Instead just open the raw XML file and edit it directly.  To do this

- Close the file
- Right click on the file in solution explorer and select "Open With"
- Choose the XML editor

Also I encourage you to file a bug on connect about this behavior.

- http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio

Comment: Thanks.  I try to edit the raw XAMLX file as much as I can, but with 30K plus lines, it isn't so easy to find stuff!  Moreover, I am mostly adding activities or moving them around and things like that - not something I can do directly in the raw file.  Something that should take 30 minutes is taking an entire day.  I am installing this patch but not sure if it will help. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3556

Comment: I posted feedback.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727651/vs2010-wf4-ide-painfully-slow

Comment: Thanks for the link to KB2468871 which i found more info on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/08/09/patch-to-improve-perf-and-reliability-of-the-workflow-designer.aspx

Comment: You might want to try the Visual Studio 11 Developer preview.  It should be faster.

Comment: Thanks Ron.  Unfortunately, this is a production application that I built in VS2010 last year and it is too late to install VS11 developer on our machines at this point for this project.  I wish we could, though.  I would like to see what performance improvements there are in VS11 related to WF stuff.